# Is it possible in vim to direct read into a new buffer?

Tags: vim, pipe

I've been able to find a lot of things working in the other direction, but so far I'm not having much luck.

I want to be able to `read` from the command line into a new buffer. I'd expect to have something like:

```
:r!tac % | new
```

and the new buffer would contain the output of `tac %`

Is there any reasonable way to do this?

Comment: You could try `:new | r!tac %`

Comment: Or `:enew | r!tac %` to open one in the same window instead of a split window

Comment: when I do that I get `E449: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wasn't considering what the `tac %` command actually did. The method I described was the same as "open a new buffer first, then redirect the read into that buffer" but I didn't consider that `%` would have been an invalid file name for a "[No Name]" buffer.

Comment: That's OK - it led me to the solution - using `#`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ahah - It turns out the answer is to use `#`, which I guess is the last used buffer(?)

```
:enew | r!tac #
```

Will read the output of `tac <current buffer>` into the new buffer.